# Create a toolbar within the Eclipse text editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an Eclipse plugin in which **I need a toolbar within the text editor as like the toggle breadcrumb view**. Is there any generic utility class in Eclipse that allows me to do this?

```
@Override
protected ISourceViewer createSourceViewer(Composite parent,
                                           IVerticalRuler ruler, 
                                           int styles)
{
    composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(1, true);
    gridLayout.numColumns = 1;
    gridLayout.marginHeight = 0;
    gridLayout.marginWidth = 0;
    composite.setLayout(gridLayout);

    ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar(composite, SWT.FLAT);
    GridData gridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false);
    toolBar.setLayoutData(gridData);
    toolBarManager = new ToolBarManager(toolBar);

    return super.createSourceViewer(composite, ruler, styles);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an text editor based on the `org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor` class, then you must override `AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.createSourceViewer(Composite parent, ...)`. Basically

- Create new top `Composite` in `parent` with a `GridLayout(1, false)`. (This is needed as the `Composite` in the `parent` argument have a `FillLayout`).
- Create a `ToolBarManager` and do 'mng.createControl(top)' with `GridData(FILL, TOP, true, false)`.
- Create new child `Composite` in top of with `GridData(FILL, FILL, true, true)`.
- Invoke `super.createSourceViewer(child, ...)`.

Comment: i was trying this by above code pls correct it, wat is going wrong in this code.

Comment: You need to create a second `Composite` - see item 3 above - which you pass to the super-call.

Comment: I have added following line in above code  but now it overlaps the editor that was to open..                                   Composite child = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
child.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true));return super.createSourceViewer(child, ruler, styles);

Answer (score 2):

Tony's answer is good, but sometimes the
`super.createSourceViewer(composite, ruler, styles);`
will change the parent's layout, the real editor area will missing just as RTA commented in Tony's answer.
I met this problem when i want to do the exactly thing as RTA.
Here is my solution:

```
@Override
protected ISourceViewer createSourceViewer(Composite parent,
        IVerticalRuler ruler, int styles) {
    changeParentLayout(parent);
    Label label = createPathLabel(parent);
    ISourceViewer viewer = super.createSourceViewer(parent, ruler, styles);
    updateSourceViewerLayout(parent, label);
    return viewer;
}

//change the parent layout to grid layout,
//so that the source file area can be shown
protected void changeParentLayout(Composite parent) {
    parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
}

//i need a label here, ToolBar will be the same
protected Label createPathLabel(Composite parent) {
    Label lblNewLabel = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
    lblNewLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.TOP, true, false, 1, 1));
    lblNewLabel.setText(getFilePath());
    return lblNewLabel;
}

//after adding the label i need and call super.createSourceViewer()
//now all widgets are ready, we need to change the editor area's layout data to grid data
//here if you only have two widgets: label and area, you can directly choose the edit area widget. i used a loop to find all sub widgets
protected void updateSourceViewerLayout(Composite parent, Label label) {
    Control[] children = parent.getChildren();
    if (children.length < 2) return;
    for (Control child : children) {
        if (child != label) {
            child.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
        }
    }
}

private String getFilePath() {
    //get the path I want
    return "";
}
```